# How do I add required permissions to an Azure Active Directory (AAD) application using the Azure PowerShell SDK?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, permissions, azure-active-directory, daemon

In my scenario, I'm attempting to automate creation of one of my AAD applications in order for it to make calls to another another WebAPI service (different AAD app) using the instructions laid out for Daemon processes here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon/

I've been able to automate creation of the AAD application and the required access key via PowerShell.

Here's how I create the application with the key added:

```
# Generate all the keys (secrets) for the AAD application.
$passwordCredentials = @()

foreach ($key in $activeDirectoryApplication.Keys.Key)
{
    $keyKeyVaultName = $key.KeyVaultName
    $keyName = $key.KeyVaultKeyName
    $expiration = $key.Expiration

    LogInfo "Generating key with key name '$keyName' into key vault '$keyKeyVaultName' with key expiry of '$expiration'."
    $passwordCredential = GenerateActiveDirectoryApplicationKeyPasswordCredential $key
    $passwordCredentials += $passwordCredential

    PublishActiveDirectoryApplicationKeyToKeyVault $key $passwordCredential
}

$existingApplication = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName -HomePage $applicationHomePage -IdentifierUris @($applicationIdentifier) -PasswordCredentials $passwordCredentials
```

What I can't figure out is how to automate step 8 in the above link where it grants permissions to access the WebAPI application:

> 8. Configure Permissions for your application - in the Settings menu, choose the 'Required permissions' section, click on Add, then Select an API, and type 'TodoListService' in the textbox. Then, click on Select Permissions and select 'Access TodoListService'.

Does anyone know if this is possible with the Azure PowerShell SDK or do I need to do it some other way (maybe the AAD Graph API)?

Thanks!

Comment: Requesting AD Application API permissions are covered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42166700/1548275

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign permissions you would need to use `New-AzureRmRoleAssignment`. That will allow you to assign permissions to an object (user\group\application) at a certain scope. if you need built-in role you are good to go. if you need to create a role use `New-AzureRmRoleDefinition`.

```
$role = Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition "Virtual Machine Contributor"
$role.Id = $null
$role.Name = "Classic storage reader"
$role.Actions.Clear()
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/read")
$role.AssignableScopes.Clear()
$role.AssignableScopes.Add("/subscriptions/xxxx")
New-AzureRmRoleDefinition -Role $role
```

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-powershell
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermroleassignment?view=azurermps-4.1.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermroledefinition?view=azurermps-4.1.0

Comment: I think the original question is about AD App API permissions, not about role assignments.