# Assigning AppRole in a programmatic way?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cloud-shell

My colleague is trying to assign AppRole to users in a programmatic way, so that we can allow our  admins to add role from our web application UI. It seems that currently there is no api for this (this api is just for built-in roles).

Apparently it's possible to do this via CloudShell, but still someone needs to open cloud shell from browser and do this. So is there anyway to achieve this task in a programmatic way or do we need to do it manually  always?

Currently we are doing this manually by changing our manifest file from Portal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure a new Azure AD application through Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164581/how-to-configure-a-new-azure-ad-application-through-powershell)

Comment: You can also call Azure AD Graph API programmatically to do the same things PowerShell does in the answer I linked.

Comment: i can't use powerShell as I have Mac