# Azure Active Diretcory Enterprise App - App ownership

Tags: azure-active-directory

In the Azure AD App registration, we have ‘Owners’ tab. It show ‘In addition to users with permission to manage any applications, the users listed here can view and edit this application registration.’. Our documentation show, ‘Change application properties, such as the name and permissions the app requests’

Will the app owner be able change ‘API permissions’  / ‘Grant consent’  / ‘add a permission’ etc. ? If yes, how do they do that (Programmatically, APIs, PowerShell module  ?)

App ownership image  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwc7T.jpg

Comment: If my reply is helpful, click mark on the left of my reply to accept it as the answer. Or any concern let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The app owner will be able to change/add the API permission, but he will not be able to grant consent to the permissions which `ADMIN CONSENT REQUIRED`, to require end users to consent to an application each time they authenticate, append `&prompt=consent` to the authentication request URL, more details see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent).

To change/add the API permissions to the AD App, you could use powershell, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164581/how-to-configure-a-new-azure-ad-application-through-powershell).

```
$req = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$acc1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d","Scope"
$acc2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "798ee544-9d2d-430c-a058-570e29e34338","Role"
$req.ResourceAccess = $acc1,$acc2
$req.ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId 1048db5f-f5ff-419b-8103-1ce26f15db31 -RequiredResourceAccess $req
```